# TWIG - Load template with applying a default filters

Tags: php, twig

I want to apply a filter by default on all my variables, to avoid this :

```
{% set var = "%gg% man" %}
{% block body %}
<h1>You are a {{ var|replace({'%gg%':good, '%bb%':bad}) }}</h1>
{% block body %}
```

on output :
**You are a good man**

is there a solution ?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please explain what you mean by *to avoid this*: do you refer to the first line? The third?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a filter twig.

```
// src/AppBundle/Twig/AppExtension.php
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('customReplace', array($this, 'customReplaceFilter')),
        );
    }

    public function customReplaceFilter(yourArguments)
    {
        //do your replace here in PHP

        return [your string after replace];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}
```

And in your twig

```
{{ var|customReplace(yourArguments) }}
```

And don't forget this in your app/config/services.yml :

```
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer,
But, I'm using Twig without Symfony.
so, i don't have `src/AppBundle/Twig/` path.

I have another issue, when the replace argument has an HTML tag, the output is escaped !

1 - How can I create the filter extension without symfony framework ?
2 - How can I get the right display of the tags on the browser without disable the escape filter ?

Comment: My answer is for symfony 2. source: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html